# Blazor Web App reloads page when saving a file to wwwroot

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor Web App that receives complete HTML files from an API. The app is supposed to display such files inside an `<object>` or `<iframe>`.
My idea was to store the files in "wwwroot/temp" and then use "/temp/" as the source for the object/iframe.
However, as soon as I store a new file in "wwwroot/temp", Blazor reloads the full page.

I suspect that the wwwroot folder is somehow tracked, and that any change to that folder triggers the reload. If that is the case, I need a way to prevent this, or another folder that I can access and that isn't tracked. But maybe this suspicion is completely wrong.

In order to recreate the issue, I created a small sample project which shows the same behaviour:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorSaveHtmlDemo.Model

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model=Model OnValidSubmit=OnValidSubmit>
    <p>
        <label for="Filename">Filename:</label>
        <br />
        <InputText id="Filename" maxlength="32" @bind-Value=Model.Filename />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Content">Content:</label>
        <br />
        <InputText id="Content" maxlength="32" @bind-Value=Model.Content />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </p>
</EditForm>

@if (iFrameSrc is not null)
{
    <iframe src=@iFrameSrc style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></iframe>
}

@code {
    private CreateHtmlFileModel Model = new();
    private String? iFrameSrc = null;

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        var localPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot"), "temp");
        if (!Directory.Exists(localPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
        var filename = Model.Filename + ".html";
        var localFile = Path.Combine(localPath, filename);
        File.WriteAllText(localFile, $@"
<html>
<head>
<title>{Model.Filename}</title>
</head>
<body>
{Model.Content}
</body>
</html>
");
        iFrameSrc = "/wwwroot/temp/" + filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this behavior also happens when you publish the app, and deploy/run it somewhere, (instead of in the local devserver) - This could be local behavior related to Hot Reload

Comment: Side note but have you thought about the scenario where 2 users use the same filename?

Comment: @HenkHolterman this is just example code. There won't be duplicate filenames in the "real" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suspect that the wwwroot folder is somehow tracked

Yes, that is part of the hot reload and debugging features.

Your program will work in Release mode, and of course after a Publish.

So either work without the debugger or stash that url in localstorage.

BTW: don't include  /wwwroot in the src="" part, just "/temp".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I believe it'll be probably caused by some values in appsettings.json, or in .csproj file.